# SQLAlchemy session.add() doesn't update

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
def update_user(user):
session.close()

get_user = session.query(User).filter(User.uniq_id == user.uniq_id).first()
print(get_user.state)  # 0
get_user.__dict__.update(user.__dict__)
print(get_user.state)  # 2

try:
    session.add(get_user)
    session.commit()
    return True, "complete"
except Exception as exc:
    session.rollback()
    exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
    file_name = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
    print(str(exc_type) + str(file_name) + str(exc_tb.tb_lineno) + "\n" + str(exc))
    return False, str(str(exc_type) + str(file_name) + str(exc_tb.tb_lineno) + "\n" + str(exc))
pass
```

The function gets a class with the cells of the table (I need use another class for use user data)
after session.add(get_user) and session.commit() values in database doesn't update

Maybe problem in `get_user.__dict__.update(user.__dict__)`

But i don't have an alternative solution

if i use `session.add(User(**user.__dict__))`, I get an error:
`(psycopg2.IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_pkey"`

Comment: `Session.add()` is for adding new (transient) objects to the session. `get_user` is persistent and already in the session. `get_user.__dict__.update(user.__dict__)` is indeed problematic. You've explicitly circumvented the ORM instrumentation, handled by descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

```
session.query(User).filter(User.uniq_id == user.uniq_id).update(user.__dict__)
```

I need use update from session.query